# Did Arjun ask Krishna to become his charioteer?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna

Did Arjun asked Krishna to become his charioteer ?
Or Did Krishna become the saarthi (charioteer) himself ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [Mahabharata: Udhyog Parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05007.htm), Arjuna requested Lord Krishna to become his charioteer:

> Krishna, the Creator of the world, clad in yellow attire, addressed Kiritin, saying, 'For what reason is it that you have selected me who will not fight at all?'
>
> "Thereupon Arjuna answered, 'I question not that you are able to slay them all. I also am alone capable of slaying them, O best of men. But you are an illustrious person in the world; and this renown will accompany you. I also am a suitor for fame; therefore, you have been selected by me. **It hath been always my desire to have you for driving my car [chariot]**. I, therefore, ask you to fulfil my desire cherished for a long time.'
>
> "Vasudeva's son thereupon said, It beseems thee well, O Kunti's son, that thou measurest thyself with me. **I will act as thy charioteer; let thy wish be fulfilled**.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Bhagavata 1.15.17](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/15/17/), Arjuna engaged Krishna as his charioteer.

This is spoken by Arjuna when he remembered Krishna after his departure from this world.

> It was by His mercy only that my enemies neglected to kill me when I
> descended from my chariot to get water for my thirsty horses. And it
> was due to my lack of esteem for my Lord that **I dared engage Him as my
> chariot driver**, for He is worshiped and offered services by the best
> men to attain salvation.